# select all nodes in java tree

Tags: java, tree, selectall

I would insert from right menu the option to select all the nodes of a tree.
This functionality is implemented in standard pressing ctrl-a. How do I similura that functionality?

```
JTree tree = new JTree();

JPopupMenu popMenuTree = new JPopupMenu();
 JMenuItem selectAll = new JMenuItem();selectAll.setText("SelectAll");
    selectAll.setActionCommand("selectAll");

    KeyStroke ctrlXKeyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("control A");
    selectAll.setAccelerator(ctrlXKeyStroke);
    popMenuTree.add(selectAll);
```

thank you so much

Comment: from menu just add shortcut for cntrl A

Comment: I tried this line of code does not work ...          selectAll.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK));                                                               I can not understand your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Because popup menus, unlike regular menus, aren't always contained by a component, accelerators in popup menu items don't work unless the popup menu is visible.